# My PC keeps restarting!

Tags: power-supply, shutdown

I have had this weird issue for a month now. I sometimes have trouble trying to initiate the PC to work. It has XP on it. When it boots it loads the progress bar then a power failure occurs. Sometimes it takes a longer time to restart (i.e: I type in my username and password) then it restarts. I noticed that the power supply's fan is not working. So is it the issue of a power supply fault?

regards, 
~Abed

Comment: Should be on Superuser.com

Answer (score 4):

As your Power Supply's fan is not working your system may get over heated and trying to shut down to save the system to protect the hardware

Comment: The power supply fan does not cool the system, it cools the power supply. You shouldn't keep trying to use a device without a fan when a fan was designed into the device. This will always end in bad things happening. Replace your power supply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change the power supply because the fan is obviously broken and therefore (as Sudantha stated) the pc is overheating and shutting down